# Can't compress with mono?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, deflatestream

I'm trying to compress some data in mono like this:

```cs
public static string Save(FlightProgram program, bool compressed)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
        if (compressed)
        {
            using (DeflateStream gz = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                f.Serialize(gz, program);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            f.Serialize(ms, program);
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()).Replace('/', '_');
    }
}
```

I'm simply getting the exception "CreateZStream". No inner exception. What's going on here ?

Stacktrace:

```
Could not save flight program: CreateZStream at   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream:CreateZStream (System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream/UnmanagedReadOrWrite,intptr)
    at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Boolean gzip) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at KSPComputerModule.ProgramSerializer.Save (KSPComputer.FlightProgram program, Boolean compressed) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at KSPComputerModule.FPComputer.OnSave (.ConfigNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  (State: None)
```

Comment: I don't actually know how Unity works, but I guess they look at the  IL code and re-compile/re-link it. Maybe they don't support the System.IO.Compression fully (see: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-binary-data-compression-with-deflatestream.31258/ )

Answer (score 6):

Surely not relevant to the OP anymore...but I finally managed to resolve this myself. It's a bug in the Mono for Windows deployment. If you delete `MonoPosixHelper.dll` files from Mono/GtkSharp directories, you'll find suddenly it works. Running Process Monitor, you can see that instead of going for the mal-compiled `MonoPosixHelper.dll`, it now goes for `libMonoPosixHelper.dll`...which is compiled correctly.

So, to resolve permanently, either delete all MonoPosixHelper.dll files so it uses libMonoPosixHelper.dll...or, preferably, use a dllmap, adding

```
 <dllmap dll="MonoPosixHelper" target="libMonoPosixHelper.dll" os="windows" />
```

to either `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\gac\System\4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll.config`(create if it doesn't already exist) or to the global Mono config at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\etc\mono\config`

Answer (score 5):

I've tested it myself and i get a DllNotFoundException:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: MonoPosixHelper
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream:CreateZStream (System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream/UnmanagedReadOrWrite,intptr)
  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Boolean gzip) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream compressedStream, CompressionMode mode) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream:.ctor (System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode)
```

The reason seems to be the CreateZStream function which is an external method which should be defined inside the MonoPosixHelper.dll.

CreateZStream is declared as

```
[DllImport("__Internal", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateZStream(CompressionMode compress, bool gzip, DeflateStream.UnmanagedReadOrWrite feeder, IntPtr data);
```

However the file "MonoPosixHelper.dll" doesn't exist. There's a libMonoPosixHelper.dylib which seems to implement an entry point for CreateZStream, however that's a library for mac.

Personally i had bad experiences with most compression code / libraries in Unity as most implementations simply wrap a native code library. According to the [compatibility page](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) the class is supported, however it looks like only the [managed part is implemented](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/17870/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-file-compression.html). [This one](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10620/dllnotfoundexception-monoposixhelpersystemiocompre.html) also seems to verify that.

I've successfully used the [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) library in a lot of projects. It's a pure managed library without native code dependencies. I've used this library in standalone, web, android and iOS builds without any problems.